# Wordpress Missing Images

Tags: images

I have an image on my site:
https://cac.bensplayground.us/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/BTA-10006078_A.jpg
But when I go to File Manager and look in the folder, it simply isn't there. HOW is that even possible? Where is the original file?

The only file that is there (that I can see) is the thumbnail (BTA-10006078_A-100x100.jpg) but not the original.

Now...this site has almost 30,000 images, so reuploading them isn't an option.

Comment: By "file manager", do you mean through FTP, cPanel (or a similar means of direct file management), or are you using the "Media" folder in the WordPress dashboard?

Comment: Filezilla, through the CPanel File Manager, etc...
When I look at the product, I see the image, I can open it in a new tab, but then when I got to find the actual file, it isn't there.